# Refresh page after deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', post , method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

After clicking, Rails deletes the current record post.

I want refresh current page after deleting.

Comment: Show the controller :delete action, please?

Comment: Rails open Post page after this, but i want stay in page

Comment: Thank you BroiSates, i change :delete action

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At your `controller` **destroy** method use the current page's url for redirect.

```
def destroy
    @object.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to current_page_url, notice: 'page was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Comment: `redirect :back` should be sufficient.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these appear to work when you are using partials.  The entire page reloads inside of the window the last partial was loaded into.  Any idea how to call redirect :back from the main window?

Answer (score 2):

in Rails 5 you can do:

```
redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
```